# Can not get the right numbers for my vat

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code is all running fine. I am having trouble with the vat part for example it would say the price without vat is £100 then the vat is £20 but when they added together it made £153 im not really sure where it gets that from
my second issue is that im trying to add a loop so I would ask do you want to work out another price and then if they say yes the whole program restarts again

```
length = int(raw_input("what is the length of all you walls added together? 
"))
while 2 > length or length > 26:
    length = int(raw_input("what is the height of all you walls added 
    together? "))
else:
    print ("okay")
height = int(raw_input("what is the length of all you walls added together? 
"))
while 1 > height or height > 6:
    height = int(raw_input("what is the height of your room? "))
else:
    print ("okay")
area = height*length
paint = raw_input("what paint would you like to use luxury paint, Standard 
quality, Economy quality? ")
if paint == "LP" or "lp" or "luxery paint":
    LP = 2
    answer = LP*area    
if paint == "SQ":
    SQ = 1.25
    answer = SQ*area    
if paint == "EQ": 
    EQ = 0.55
    answer = EQ*area
undercoat = raw_input("would you like an undercoat?")
if undercoat == "yes":
    undercoat = area*0.55
    novat = answer + undercoat
elif undercoat  == "no":
    novat = answer
percentage = (novat/100.00)*20
print percentage
cost = (novat + percentage)
print "Interior Decorator"
print "invoice"
print "the price will be "+ unichr(163) + str(answer) +"(excluding vat)"
print "the vat will be "+ unichr(163) + str(percentage)
print "your grand total is " + unichr(163) + str(cost)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Which debugger are you using to step through the program and examine the values generated?

Comment: An easy way to start debugging in Python is to paste this pdb line: `import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()` right before the code that is not doing what you expect, and examine the variables (e.g., `print(foo)`) before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding the wrong values:*

Seeing that `cost = (novat + percentage)`. Shouldn't you be using the `novat` variable instead of `answer` when printing the price?

*About looping through another execution:*

You could extract a method and loop like the examples on your code:

```
def main_logic():
    # The code you have above

while True:
    main_logic()
    run_again = raw_input("would you like to run again? ")
    if run_again != "yes":
        break
```